# Undefined Array Key ""

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am new to laravel so this particular error is giving me headache. I am trying use a datatable in laravel vue.js app. I have the following code in my laravel backend and when I try retrieving the data from the data, I get the **Undefined array key error message** in the dev tools.
How do I resolve the issue please? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public function getAccommodations(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->input('showdata')) {
        return Accommodation::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    }        

    $columns = ['name','town_city','district','email','phone'];

    $length = $request->input('length');
    $column = $request->input('column');

    $search_input = $request->input('search');

    $query = Accommodation::select('name','town_city','district','email','phone')->orderBy($columns [$column]);

    if ($search_input) {

        $query->where(function($query) use ($search_input) {

            $query->where('name', 'like', '%'. $search_input . '%')
            ->orWhere('town_city', 'like', '%'. $search_input . '%')
            ->orWhere('district', 'like', '%'. $search_input . '%')
            ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%'. $search_input . '%')
            ->orWhere('phone', 'like', '%'. $search_input . '%')

        });

    }

    $accommodations = $query->paginate($length);
    return ['data' => $accommodations];
}
```

Below is the stacktrace

```
[2022-04-24 20:00:17] local.ERROR: Undefined array key "" {"userId":2,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined array key \"\" at C:\\Users\\Nat Osei\\Desktop\\projects\\gh_diary\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\AccommodationsController.php:50)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\Users\\Nat Osei\\Desktop\\projects\\gh_diary\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions.php(231): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Undefined array...', 'C:\\\\Users\\\\Nat Os...', 50)
#1 C:\\Users\\Nat Osei\\Desktop\\projects\\gh_diary\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\AccommodationsController.php(50): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\{closure}(2, 'Undefined array...', 'C:\\\\Users\\\\Nat Os...', 50)
#2 C:\\Users\\Nat Osei\\Desktop\\projects\\gh_diary\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php(54): App\\Http\\Controllers\\AccommodationsController->getAccommodations(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#3 C:\\Users\\Nat Osei\\Desktop\\projects\\gh_diary\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('getAccommodatio...', Array)
#4 C:\\Users\\Nat Osei\\Desktop\\projects\\gh_diary\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(261): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\AccommodationsController), 'getAccommodatio...')
#5 C:\\Users\\Nat Osei\\Desktop\\projects\\gh_diary\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(204): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#6 C:\\Users\\Nat Osei\\Desktop\\projects\\gh_diary\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(725): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#7 C:\\Users\\Nat Osei\\Desktop\\projects\\gh_diary\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#8 C:\\Users\\Nat Osei\\Desktop\\projects\\gh_diary\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#9 C:\\Users\\Nat Osei\\Desktop\\projects\\gh_diary\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#10 C:\\Users\\Nat Osei\\Desktop\\projects\\gh_diary\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#11 C:\\Users\\Nat Osei\\Desktop\\projects\\gh_diary\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#12 C:\\Users\\Nat Osei\\Desktop\\projects\\gh_diary\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#13 C:\\Users\\Nat Osei\\Desktop\\projects\\gh_diary\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#14 C:\\Users\\Nat Osei\\Desktop\\projects\\gh_diary\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 C:\\Users\\Nat Osei\\Desktop\\projects\\gh_diary\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Session\\Store), Object(Closure))
```

Comment: Why are you passing an array to the second parameter of [`orderBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#ordering)?

Comment: To be able to use the columns in my vue (frontend) please.

Comment: It seems that `$column` is an empty string. Perhaps, check what data you're sending and add default fallback; `$column = $request->input('column', 'name')`

Comment: I just reformatted the code and it looks odd that the `$query` has a closure then another `$query` nested inside of it. It will never leave the scope of that function, that's probably why no keys are being returned.

Comment: @JacobMulquin I assume it's to isolate the `->orWhere` from any other (potential) `->where` statement. It doesn't need to returns something has it's a mutable query

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier Thanks for your time and response. I tried your solution but it did not work. I get the same error message.

Comment: @JacobMulquin. Thanks for your time and response. Can you please suggest a better way to go about it?

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier Interesting, I would not have thought it would have worked since the variable isn't being passed by reference but it appears like examples on Laravel docs are the same. It still reads like a redundant closure to me though.

Comment: Your information are not providing enough information to help you. Can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier Well noted! I will add it soon...

Comment: What is the code on line 50 of `AccommodationsController.php`?

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier When I used your suggested solution, "$column = $request->input('column', 'name')", I got "Undefined array key "name"" in the stacktrace.

Comment: @JacobMulquin ->orderBy($columns [$column]); is the code on line 50.

Comment: Oh right, because there's no key `name` in `['name','town_city','district','email','phone'];` The array keys are 0, 1, 2 ,3 and 4. The fallback should be `0` then `$column = $request->input('column', 0)`

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier. Thank you! When I used the index or key 0 as a fallback as you suggested, the error is solved. Thank you once again. Please how do I upvote your comment?

Comment: I have posted an answer. You can accept it with the checkmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to get an element from your array `$columns` with an empty string.

```php
$columns = ['name','town_city','district','email','phone'];

$column = $request->input('column'); // empty string

$query->orderBy($columns[$column]);
```

You can fix the issue by setting a default value

```php
$column = $request->input('column', 0); 
$query->orderBy($columns[$column]); // $columns[0]
```